# How to create coupled types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have four types, lets say A and B, and X and Y. In my case, A and X are only used together, and B and Y are only used together. How can i achieve a type/interface that lets me write this:

```
value: MyInterface = {a: A, x: X},
value: MyInterface = {a: B, x: Y},
```

but not this:

```
value: MyInterface = {a: A, x: Y},
value: MyInterface = {a: B, x: X},
```

Comment: Do you want if `a` is `A`, `x` should always be `Y` and if `a` is `B`, `x` is should always be `Y`?

Comment: No, not has you wrote it there, but i think you get it. I want the following:
If a is A, x should always be X and if a is B, x is should always be Y?
You wrote Y both times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use union type for this

```js
type A = string
type X = string[]

type B = number
type Y = number[]

type MyInterface = { a: A, x: X } | { a: B, x: Y }

const test1: MyInterface = { a: 'foo', x: ['bar', 'foobar'] } // pass
const test2: MyInterface = { a: 0, x: [1, 2] } // pass
const test3: MyInterface = { a: 0, x: ['', ''] } // error
const test4: MyInterface = { a: '', x: [1, 2] } // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwFCkigA0Fk0tsBtAXV33GgCFTMBXAWwCMJV7CBNFh26oadAtACyIAJKZgPAGYBDAMbREAbyjKAXLAA0UAB76SAXygAfKNr1RGR01EHm6qgPaYUUBSgCM+tJyCqgq6qR2+gDkih4e0U76lNGcyqiJULHxaRnUUJYA9IVQYMpISLie3sC+ECgATEGy8kpqGrY6+gAMSVCU-kYN+UUlZRVVXj5+wADMzSFtEVpdUL0mydGZWyNQxVA8qB681dP1wAAsC61h7ZGrW30DQ7v7h8dAA)

Answer (score 0):

Types would allow `MyInterface` (`MyType`) to become a Union type.

```
type AX = {
  a: A;
  x: X;
};
type BY = {
  b: B;
  y: Y;
};

type MyType = AX | BY;

const value: MyType = {
  a: "a",
  x: "x",
};
```